# Linear Transformation and Linear Independence Question

Tags: linear-algebra

I'm wondering if $T$ is a linear transformation from $V$ into $W$ and $T(\alpha_1),\ldots,T(\alpha_n)$ is linearly independent would $\alpha_1,\ldots, \alpha_n$be linearly independent? I understand that that if $T$ is non-singular and $\alpha_1,\ldots, \alpha_n$ is linearly independent then $T(\alpha_1),\ldots,T(\alpha_n)$ is linearly independent but does the converse also apply?

Comment: Yes. If $T$ is non-singular then it is bijective.  So it admits an inverse with the property you mention.

Comment: You actually don't need something as strong as $T$ being nonsingular. If $T$ is linear transformation and $\{T(\alpha_1),...,T(\alpha_n)\}$ is a linearly independent set, then $\alpha_1,...,\alpha_n$ must be L.I.

Comment: T is injective if and only if it transforms any set of linearly independent vectors into a set of linearly independent vectors. T should not be bijective but it should be injective. There is a formal demonstration on that.

Comment: @Bye_world I didn't think there was any reason to assume they were a basis, but if it is, then our statements become equivalent. If $\alpha_1,...,\alpha_n$ were already a basis, then the original part of his question doesn't make sense

Comment: (Since he is asking if $\alpha_1,..,\alpha_n$ would be independent, and if they are a basis, we already have that)

Comment: @CurtisW Sorry, I realized that was a dumb comment right after I wrote it.  Disregard.

Comment: @Bye_world No worries- If the second part of the question is read first it can lead to some confusion!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose that that $T:V\to W$ is a linear transformation and that there are $\alpha_1,...,\alpha_n\in V$ such that $T(\alpha_1),...,T(\alpha_n)$ are linearly independent in $W$. Assume that there are $\lambda_1,...,\lambda_n\in k$ (where $k$ is the base-field, it is probably $\mathbb{R}$ in your case), such that:

$$\lambda_1\alpha_1+\lambda_2\alpha_2+...+\lambda_n\alpha_n=0 .$$

Applying the linear transformation $T$ to both sides of the above equation we get:

\begin{align}
0=T(0)&=T(\lambda_1\alpha_1+\lambda_2\alpha_2+...+\lambda_n\alpha_n)\\
      &=\lambda_1T(\alpha_1)+\lambda_2 T(\alpha_2)+...+\lambda_nT(\alpha_n).
\end{align}

Since $\{T(\alpha_1),...,T(\alpha_n)\}$ is a linearly independent set, we must have: 
$$\lambda_1=\lambda_2=...=\lambda_n=0.$$

Thus, by definition $\alpha_1,...,\alpha_n$ are linearly independent.

Comment: @user184679 If Curtis answered your question you should accept it.  That way it doesn't keep popping up in the active questions every once and a while even though it's already answered.  I'm sure Curtis would also enjoy to extra rep.